# how to create and open a .db file using sqlite in pycharm

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have python code where DBM is imported and when request is open it opens the .db file or else it creates new file. Now I want to develop similar module using sqlite. So, what is the command to create new file in sqlite. I have written code now as :

```
class sqlite:

    moduleInstance = None
    def __init__(self, db_path, db_name, request):

  if request == 'open':
     self.path = (os.path.join(db_path, db_name),'open')
  else:
     self.path = (os.path.join(db_path, db_name),'c')

  def db_connect():
     print("db connection")
     con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
     c = con.cursor()
     c.commit()
```

The code is working fine but it is not creating .db file into folder.

The testscript is as follow:

```
from code import *
class Test:
    def __init__(self, db_path, db_name, request):
        self.db_path = db_path
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.code1 = sqlite(db_path, db_name, request)
     def fileopen(self, db_path, db_name, request):
        self.code2 = sqlite(db_path, db_name, request)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tst = Test('', 'sfile1.db', 'c')
    tst.fileopen('', 'file2.db', 'open')
```

Comment: Please, do not spam tags: *I have python code* and *go-sqlite3* are definitely incompatible

Comment: the code which i have posted is .py file. So if I have python code is not correct tag, then which code it is?